# winload.efi.mui possibly corrupt

Tags: windows-8

I have a windows 8 workstation which won't boot. The automatic repair fails. I got to a command prompt and ran chkdsk. It found 4 sectors with errors, all in the winload.efi.mui file. I believe the file may be corrupt.

I would like to avoid refreshing the OS because I have software on the system that I would like to preserve if possible.

--Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the repair options and select the command prompt. Here run [this DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to repair the damaged file:

`DISM /Image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` 
*(replace C: with the drive letter of your Windows)*